# Search using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Here's my first entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bills")
public class BillEntity {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private BranchEntity fromBranch;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private BranchEntity toBranch;

//Other columns
}
```

And second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Branches")
public class BranchEntity {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fromBranch")
private List<BillEntity> billsSent;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "toBranch")
private List<BillEntity> billsRecived;

//Other columns
}
```

In general, is this approach of relation OK for hibernate, to have double `@ManyToOne`s and `@OneToMany` of same entity? 
I want to find bills using Spring Data JPA repository providing ID of fromBranch.

```
public interface myBillRepository extends Repository<BillEntity, Long>
{
public List<BillEntity> findByFromBranch(Long fromBranchId);
}
```

So, can it understand that I want to search by fromBranch's ID, not toBranch's ID or vise versa? Thank You!

Comment: Well if it works, then I tend to say "yes".  But I think if it's a good idea depends on your domain model and personal opinion, therefore I guess this question is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can understand because is attribute based. The correct example for search by fromBranch's ID is:

```
public List<BillEntity> findByFromBranch_id(Long fromBranchId);
```